# Under macOS using pip install pytorch failure

Tags: macos, pip, installation, pytorch

When I'm using pip to install pytorch, some exception appeared.

Env:

1. Sys: MaxOS High Sierra
2. python version : 3.6
3. pip version : 19.0.2

input: `pip install pytorch`

output:

```
Collecting pytorch
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a9/41/4487bc23e3ac4d674943176f5aa309427b011e00607eb98899e9d951f67b/pytorch-0.1.2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pytorch
  Building wheel for pytorch (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/lw/s7b4_22d1v30nfm0wkys878w0000gn/T/pip-install-ygd1rucx/pytorch/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/lw/s7b4_22d1v30nfm0wkys878w0000gn/T/pip-wheel-p0npaj5r --python-tag cp36:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/lw/s7b4_22d1v30nfm0wkys878w0000gn/T/pip-install-ygd1rucx/pytorch/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
      raise Exception(message)
  Exception: You should install pytorch from http://pytorch.org

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pytorch
  Running setup.py clean for pytorch
Failed to build pytorch
Installing collected packages: pytorch
  Running setup.py install for pytorch ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/lw/s7b4_22d1v30nfm0wkys878w0000gn/T/pip-install-ygd1rucx/pytorch/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/lw/s7b4_22d1v30nfm0wkys878w0000gn/T/pip-record-us45ly0z/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/lw/s7b4_22d1v30nfm0wkys878w0000gn/T/pip-install-ygd1rucx/pytorch/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        raise Exception(message)
    Exception: You should install pytorch from http://pytorch.org

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/lw/s7b4_22d1v30nfm0wkys878w0000gn/T/pip-install-ygd1rucx/pytorch/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/lw/s7b4_22d1v30nfm0wkys878w0000gn/T/pip-record-us45ly0z/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/lw/s7b4_22d1v30nfm0wkys878w0000gn/T/pip-install-ygd1rucx/pytorch/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're installing an old package named [`pytorch`](https://pypi.org/project/pytorch/#history) on PyPI i.e. pytorch 0.1.2. That's why you're receiving the exception.

You're supposed to install it from the pytorch [website](https://pytorch.org/). There you'll an option to select your system configuration, it'll give you the command to install it. Also, the latest version of pytorch is named [`torch`](https://pypi.org/project/torch/#history) on PyPI. So, just do

```
pip3 install torch  # or with pip
```

If it fails due to cache, try with `-no-cache-dir` option.